Installing MTPro 2 lite
I have tried following this method to install MTPro 2 lite:
https://github.com/jamespfennell/mathtime-installer/
However, when I go to type

chmod +x ./mtpro2-texlive.sh

into the terminal, it tells me

chmod: Unable to change file mode on ./mtpro2-texlive.sh: Operation not permitted

How do I go about fixing this?
Thanks.

Try sudo chmod ...?

It responds

chmod: Unable to change file mode on ./mtpro2-texlive.sh: Operation not permitted


First of what Operating system are you on? Can you run bash mtpro2-texlive.sh (that is normally the same as giving it execute rights and running it).

macOS Sonoma 14.5. I get the response >bash: mtpro2-texlive.sh: Operation not permitted.

I don't think that you need some special installer. As far as remember you can simply use the texmf from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mtp2lite (perhaps you need to move the map from dvips to fonts/map) and then call updmap-sys to enable the map file.

Checked that, there is a map file in both directories. I tried deleting the one in texmf, and calling updmap-sys in terminal, and it gave the following error message > updmap: Directory "/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap" isn't writable: No such file or directory at /Library/TeX/texbin/updmap line 1464.

you need sudo sh mtpro2-texlive.sh to run the script and sudo updmap-sys enable <name of map file>. it should ask for your password.

the second command worked, but the first still gives the same error message i.e., > sh: mtpro2-texlive.sh: Operation not permitted

what happens if you just try to invoke bash i.e. bash? if that seems to work, what does echo $SHELL return? if that includes bash, try running sudo chmod +x mtpro2-texlive.sh. if that doesn't work, what does ls -alhZ . give? (it may give an error - I'm not sure which options are supported on BSD. if so, try ls -l . instead.)

This is the output I get:
bash-3.2$ echo $SHELL

/bin/zsh
bash-3.2$ sudo chmod +x mtpro2-texlive.sh
chmod: Unable to change file mode on mtpro2-texlive.sh: Operation not permitted

